# how to output a triangle using '*'

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code and I'm getting errors when running. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how I should correct it?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, x;
    x = 1;
    i = 0;

    while (i < x) 
    {
        cout << "*";
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with design patterns. And the first thing to do, when getting an error, is to read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  Can you tell us what you expect the code to do, and share the errors it gives you?  There's a handy FAQ to help you formulate your questions so that people can answer them well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `void main` eh?

Comment: And read up about for loops

Comment: Change `void main{` to `int main(){`

Comment: Describe the exact error message, or you'll be down-voted.

Comment: `while (i < x)` will not run that many times if `i` is just *one* less than `x`.

Answer (score 1):

As other said, you need to change:

```
void main
{
}

//change to 

int main()
{
}
```

I don't believe your program will work properly.
Use nested for loops to print your triangle like so:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < (11 - row - 1); col++)
      cout << "@ ";
    for (int col = (11 - row); col < 11; col++)
      cout << "  ";
    cout << endl;
  }
```

This will give you the output of:

```
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ @
@ @ @ @
@ @ @
@ @
@
```

If you want to change the shape of the triangle (have the 90 degree angle in a different corner all you would have to do is change the conditions in the for loops.

Here is another example with the corner in a different position:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
      cout << "@ ";
    for (int col = row; col < 11; col++)
      cout << "  ";
    cout << endl;
  }
```

I'm sure you get the idea now... Just play with changing the conditions in the for loops until you get your desired output.